# Appending to body with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment to make several bugs fly around the screen randomly, but I'm having problems getting divs to be added to the html body through javascript.

```
<head>
<title>Fly little bug! Fly!</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var numBugs = 0;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
function bug(startX, startY, xSpeed, ySpeed){
  var self = this;
  this.xPos = startX;
  this.yPos = startY;
  this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
  this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
  this.divId = "bug" + numBugs;

  this.div = document.createElement("div");

  this.div.innerHTML = "test";

  body.appendChild(self.div);

  this.fly = function(){
    self.xPos += self.xSpeed;
    self.yPos += self.ySpeed;
  }
  this.fly();
  this.flyInterval = setInterval(function(){ self.fly(); },5000);
  numBugs++;
}

/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>

<body onload = "var bug1 = new bug(10, 20, 5, 3);">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: Every DOM method that contains the word "Elements" (notice the s at the end? Plural!) returns a *list* of DOM nodes, not a single DOM node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems.

1. The getElementsByTagName function returns an array of elements. You have to be explicit that you want the first element of the array.

   ```
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
   ```

   You're essentially saying "give me all the tags in the document of type 'body'". It gives you a list of tags, and you have to get the first one even though there should only be one "body" in any HTML document. The `[0]` in the code above gives you the first one.
2. You are trying to access the body before it's created. The <script> occurs in the document before the <body> tag, so at the time the script is executed, the body doesn't exist. You need to move the call to getElementsByTagName inside the bug() function.

Comment: I added in the [0] and it still didn't work. I also added alert() messages before and after the line: body.appendChild(self.div);
only the first one worked, so I know this is where the error is.

Comment: Edited answer. I think I found the other mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div>Div Content</div>';
```

Look into jQuery if you want to make simple DOM manipulation easier on yourself.